# mutliple onsubmit handlers for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, events, closures, handler, onsubmit

I'm writing a bolt-on bit of javascript which is intended to capture information when a form is submitted. I need to accomodate the scenario where there may be multiple forms on a web page, none/some/all of which may already have onsubmit handlers defined....and I need to fire the original handler after calling the bolt-on code.

I've got a test case setup with 2 forms, the first has no onsubmit handler, the second a simple alertbox.

I tried the code below - but that seemed to copy the pre-existing handler from form2 into form1:

```
window.onload=pageinit;

function pageinit()
{
    for (var x=0; x < document.forms.length; x++) {
            var origSubmit=document.forms[x].onsubmit;
            if (typeof origSubmit != 'function') {
                    document.forms[x].onsubmit=dosubmit;
            } else {
                    document.forms[x].onsubmit = function (event) {
                            dosubmit(event);
                            return origSubmit(event);
                    }
            }
    }
}

function dosubmit(ev)
{
  alert('bolt-on invoked from ' + ev.target.name);  
}
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get what you want to do, but you have the typical *function in loop definition* problem:

At the the time when any `document.forms[x].onsubmit` function is called (obviously after the loop finished), `origSubmit` in each handler will point to the same function (`document.forms[document.forms.length - 1].onsubmit`). You have to "capture" the value of `origSubmit` because JavaScript has only function scope, not block scope:

```
 for (var x=0; x < document.forms.length; x++) {
            var origSubmit=document.forms[x].onsubmit;
            if (typeof origSubmit != 'function') {
                    document.forms[x].onsubmit=dosubmit;
            } else {
                    document.forms[x].onsubmit = (function(func) {
                        return function (event) {
                                dosubmit(event);
                                return func(event);
                               }
                    }(origSumbit));
            }
    }
```

See also [*Closures for Dummies*](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html), Example 5

Comment: Thanks Felix, yes - that certainly works - I need to have a wee think about why now - so I'll go read that link. Unfortunately in MSIE6, the event object seems to go astray somewhere - but I get the same problem with attachEvent.

Comment: @symcbean: IE does not pass the event object directly. You get it via `window.event`. Read about events here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html and this could also be interesting: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may be your `origSubmit` variable; it is 'closed' over the function you create there but it's changed by the for loop.

Try:

```
function pageinit()
{
    for (var x=0; x < document.forms.length; x++) {
            var origSubmit=document.forms[x].onsubmit;
            if (typeof origSubmit != 'function') {
                    document.forms[x].onsubmit=dosubmit;
            } else {
                    document.forms[x].onsubmit = createSubmitHandler(origSubmit);
            }
    }
}

function dosubmit(ev)
{
  alert('bolt-on invoked from ' + ev.target.name);  
}


function createSubmitHandler(origSubmit) 
{
  return function(event) {
    dosubmit(event);
    return origSubmit(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sje397 - unfortunately I Felix has given me the same answer and I can't accept them both - so you get a vote instead :)